# Could a Time Lord become god-like being, like Rose in "The Parting of the Ways"?

Tags: doctor-who

In ["The Parting of the Ways"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Parting_of_the_Ways), Rose became a <s>deus ex machina</s> powerful creature, capable of removing all Daleks from space and time (till the next time they came back). Has it been addressed anywhere if The Doctor would have gotten this power if he'd been the one to look at the Time Vortex?

Comment: It's a good question, but you also have to remember that taking that energy from Rose, and into himself, is what killed the 9th Doctor. That leads me to believe that it's too much for even a Time Lord to absorb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes, if not more powerful

This is addressed explicitly in ["Utopia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(Doctor_Who)):

> **Doctor:** [Rose] came back. Opened the heart of the Tardis and absorbed the time vortex itself.
>
> **Jack:** What does that mean, exactly?
>
> **Doctor:** No one's ever meant to have that power. If a Time Lord did that, he'd become a god. A vengeful god. But she was human.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Doctor:** Everything she did was so human. She brought you back to life but she couldn't control it.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Series 3 Episode 11: "Utopia"</sup>

The Doctor's phrasing here would seem to imply that Rose's use of that power was limited by her humanity; it would seem that a Time Lord would have become even more powerful than Rose had been. Since this idea was never developed further, we can only speculate on just how *much* more powerful they would become.

Comment: I wonder why no time lord did this in the time war.

Comment: @DoctorTwo Presumably there are extremely undesirable side-effects, though again we can only speculate as to what those might be. Alternately, perhaps there are some lines even the desperate Time Lords weren't willing to cross; we know that, for example, they refrained from using the Moment

Comment: I dunno. I don't read that as a time lord being more powerful so much as knowing what they could do with that power versus Rose's operating on instincts. And Rose's humanity tempering her actions as opposed to a Time Lord exerting their will upon all of spacetime.

Comment: @DoctorTwo - for that matter, you have to wonder why The Master never attempted this. He even had unfettered access to the Vortex in the Doctor Who telefilm from 1996, along with a couple other instances.

Comment: @Broklynite I see the distinction you're making, but I don't know that I'd call it a meaningful difference; either way, if pressed, I know which one I'd rather run into on a dark spaceship

Comment: @JasonBaker fair enough